# Error fetch from react to express without CRA(create-react-app)

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express, http-proxy

```
import React,{Component} from 'react';
import '../styles/App.css';

class App extends Component{
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      products: []
    };
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    fetch('http://localhost:4000/products', {
      method: 'GET',
      mode: "no-cors",
      headers: {"Content-Type": "application/json"}
    }).then(res => {console.log(res);res.json()})
      .then(products => this.setState({products}));
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>Hello, react.js!!!</h1>
        <ul>
        {this.state.products.map(product => <li>{product.product_name}</li>)}
        </ul>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

express.js listen port 4000.
This express.js part

```
app.get("/products", (req, res) => {
    conn.query('SELECT * FROM products', (err, result) => {
        if(err) {throw err;}
        console.log(result);

        res.json(result);
    });
});
```

If I just type in the address bar http://localhost:4000/products, then I will get a json response, but in the component application react.JS fetch returns an error because the response contains an empty body, which means that the address was not available. This error is related to CORS, but I don't know how to fix it.

Perhaps if you know how to use and configure a proxy for this, then I would be very grateful for a hint.

App.js uses fetch to access express

here are the error logs, it occurs because the body in the request is null, that is, the response comes with an empty body
[image]

Comment: Can you please post the error also?

Comment: published an image of the error

Comment: I think in your first then block you need to do `return await res.json()`

Comment: there is an error because the request body is null

Comment: Have you tried awaiting `res.json()`? `res.json()` returns a promise and you need to wait for the promise to be resolved

Comment: you can help, I don't know much about it

Comment: As suggested in answer also please remove the line from render where you're calling `componentDidMount()`. It's a react life-cycle method and life-cycle methods are called automatically by React itself

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whats happening is your code is not waiting for the call to finish.

You can use `async-await` functionality.
This link may help : https://www.valentinog.com/blog/await-react/

Editing and adding a sample as OP is not able to reach the link.
Try this:

```
  async componentDidMount() {
const response = await fetch('http://localhost:4000/products', {
      method: 'GET',
      mode: "no-cors",
      headers: {"Content-Type": "application/json"}
    });
    const json = await response.json();
    // Do stuff with json
    console.log(json);
    this.setState(json);
  }
```

As simple as this might also work but please check:

```
  async componentDidMount() {
    await fetch('http://localhost:4000/products', {
      method: 'GET',
      mode: "no-cors",
      headers: {"Content-Type": "application/json"}
    }).then(res => {console.log(res);res.json()})
      .then(products => this.setState({products}));
  }
```

Also have you enabled `CORS` in your express project?

Comment: Edited the answer! Please try now.

Comment: how do I do this.setState in this case?I need to wait for json now, but I don't know how

Comment: Edited further.

Comment: error in console - 'ReferenceError: regeneratorRuntime is not defined' - what else you need to enable?

Comment: Can you check if the call is working. If yes, this may be after the call worked. What is the console saying?

Comment: .then does not work, because I tried to output the result to the console, but there is simply no result. I also tried to print 123 in the same place and it didn't work

Comment: Can you please try the first approach? I edited again.

Answer (score 0):

You dont need to `this.componentDidMount();`. Delete that line. It will self-execute as is part of react component lifecycle.